# Finding the 1st and 2nd occurrence of a regex in a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

If I have a string such as

```
First timing is 10:10:30, second timing is 11:12:45, third is 12:14:25
```

How do I get only the first and second occurrence of timing that is formatted to show only the minutes and seconds?

The end result should be 2 strings for example,

```
string1 = 10:10
string2 = 11:12
```

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us your code and whats the prob?

Comment: Why not just find all `\d+:\d+(?=:\d+)` and grab the first two from the array?

Comment: You could add a comma to get the first 2 from the example string [`\d+:\d+(?=:\d+,)`](https://regex101.com/r/MoQ3FA/1)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var regEx = /timing[^\d]+(\d+:\d+)/ig;
var text = 'First timing is 10:10:30, second timing is 11:12:45, third is 12:14:25'
var match = regEx.exec(text);

while(match !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = regEx.exec(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "First timing is 10:40:30, second timing is 11:12:45, 
    third is 12:14:25";
    myString = myString.replaceAll("[a-zA-z]","");
    String[] numbers = myString.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
             System.out.println("string"+(i+1)+" = "+numbers[i].substring(0,numbers[i].length()-3));     
    }

}
```

Output
`string1 = 10:40
string2 = 11:12
string3 = 12:14`